# Web Application, WCF Service and Sharepoint Web Service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, sharepoint, authentication

Okay so scenario goes like this :

I have multiple web applications, which consume a wcf service. and now i am making a change to wcf service to consume Sharepoint 2010 Web Service i.e. UserprofileService.asmx

**Web Application - > WCF Service - > Sharepoint WebService**

And the problem is if i use the below code in wcf service, it works fine with the Sharepoint Service, and i am able to access the methods available in sharepoint userprofile service, when i test the wcf service from my machine.

**C#**

```
        service.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
        service.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

**Web.config**

```
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly"> 
<transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None" 
realm="" /> 
<message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" /> 
</security>
```

But i am no longer able to call the WCF Service from my web application as the web application uses the below.

```
<security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="">
              <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never"/>
            </transport>
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true"/>
          </security>
```

I need a way to configure WCF Service in such a way, that it still be able to talk with all the existing applications, and be able to talk to Sharepoint Service at the same time.

Most Importantly i want to use the service account(Ex: b2\deltaUser) under which WCF service runs to access the profiles of different users in share point userprofile service. Do i need to use impersonation ? If yes, how can i use it here.

Comment: This sounds like it could be a case of the "double hop" problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was easy. To create two separate bindings and that did the trick. :)